# Issue with java BigDecimal storing garbage value

Tags: java, bigdecimal, double-precision

```
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(0.05);
    System.out.println(b);
```

Output:

```
    0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125
```

How to handle this ?

Comment: That's not a "garbage value". That's the double precision floating-point representation of 0.05.

Comment: See also the Java Puzzlers presentation of this (and other) topics: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Java-Puzzlers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number is strictly correct.  This is the exact value 0.05 as a double is.  This is because `double` cannot represent all values exactly and instead must give you the closest representable value.  When you print the value, it assumes you want to round it, and hides the representation error.  BigDecimal is just showing you what the value really is.

If you want to convert from a double to a BigDecimal and have it round the way you expect use

```
BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.05);
```

Another solution is to not use BigDecimal.  If you use `double` with appropriate rounding, you will get the same answer, with a lot less code and much faster code.

Comment: LOL I really love java's BigDecimal. Especially because it's really nice to write [code that uses it](http://whyjavasucks.com/Blog/6/Java_vs_CSharp/4092/Operator_Overloading_Is_Useless_By_Example).

Comment: @HighCore I love BigDecimal too.  I recently came across this one in a risk management system, using BigDecimal `(43 / 7) * 7 != 43`.

Comment: I'm being sarcastic dude.. Check the link.

Comment: @HighCore I "love" that BigDecimal still gets rounding errors after all the pain you go through to use them.

Comment: yeah.. people from the middle ages also suffered the lack of proper technology. Thank God we live in 2014 and we can use modern languages that support proper operator overloading such as C#.

Comment: BTW, in 2014, there are languages that also [do math properly](http://ideone.com/3edSiN).

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to this

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.05");
```

when you pass `0.05` it is by default `double` value and that is how it gets represented in double

Comment: `0.5` is a `double` not a `float`, as is `0.05`.  This converts a String. but if you want to convert a double, use `valueOf(double)`

Comment: @Peter yes you are right about `double`, corrected thanks and +1